# Removing S0 record form SREC file

Tags: vxworks, objcopy

I'm working on embedded system running on WindRiver's VxWorks 653. After building binary files converted to SREC with objcopy for burning into target device. But this SREC files contain an S0 record with directory where it was built, so build same code placed in two different directories will end with different SREC files. Is it possible to turn off this S0 record adding to result file, without manual operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply post-process the output of `objcopy` with `grep` to remove any `S0` record, e.g.:

```
objcopy ... -O srec input_file temp_file && \
grep -v ^S0 temp_file > output_file && \
rm temp_file
```